# How far from the TV/Internet splitter can I place the cable modem?

Tags: cable-modem, splitter

Does my cable modem for my internet need to be connected right at the point where the cable comes into my house?  In other words can I split the input cable for the TV and Internet at the entry point but then run a cable for the Internet through my basement up to a back bedroom so I can place the cable modem in there?

Comment: In theory: Yes, you can. However a signal will weaken in a cable so if you take this to extremes then you might run into problems. (no idea what extremes are here: a few meters? dozens of meters? hundreds of meters?)

Comment: Why not leave the cable modem where it is and just run an ethernet cable to your back bedroom? Max length for a Cat-5 ethernet cable is 100m ...

Answer (score 1):

Yes, in any normal sized house, you can use a typical Cable splitter and run a RG6/RG59 cable to another location where the cable modem is placed.

Neither the loss through the cable splitter (they're often marked with dB) nor the loss through the additional length of cable will be enough to degrade a cable-modem signal for a home user.